# Force Excel 2007 to open files in one instance / window of Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I'd like to force Excel 2007 to open files in the same window by default. Instructions which I was able to found so far don't help and usually solve quite opposite problem... Can somebody assist with how to control this behaviour (Windows 7, Office 2007)?

Answer (score 0):

This is the only setting that has an effect on this behavior:

[image]

But, as you've already noticed yourself, this can cause other issues.

It's sad, but there seems to be no proper solution. If you want multiple windows, you'll have to start multiple instances of Excel.